# Python: Sort, randomize specific attributes, then manipulate

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

I need to find the lowest attribute value, add 1, as well as randomly manipulate a random attribute value for a given set of class instance attributes. My 'Player' class has many attributes,

```
    self.name = name
    self.level = 1
    self.experience = 0
    self.gold = 500000
    self.wielded_weapon = short_sword
    self.armor = padded_armor
    self.shield = no_shield
    self.boots = leather_boots
```

but I am concerned with these 6:

```
        self.strength = 15  
        self.dexterity = 14  
        self.constitution = 13  
        self.intelligence = 12 
        self.wisdom = 8  
        self.charisma = 10
```

I originally tried sorting a list, and then moved to a dictionary and tried..

```
ability_dict = {1: self.strength, 2: self.dexterity, 3: self.constitution, 4: self.intelligence, 5: self.wisdom, 6: self.charisma}
```

I tried:

```
        min_value = min(ability_dict.values())
        min_value += 1
```

and

```
rndm_attribute = random.choice(list(ability_dict.values()))
rndm_attribute +=1
```

And also:

```
        minimum_key = min(ability_dict, key=ability_dict.get)
        ability_dict[minimum_key] += 1
```

I learned that I am not affecting the actual attributes of the object, but merely *values* in the list or dictionary.
How can I sort, randomize and then manipulate the attributes themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the __dict__ attribute of your class. By editing player.__dict__ directly, or a variable which you derived from it (player_dict in the code below),  you can edit your object's attributes.

```
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.strength = 15
        self.dexterity = 14
        self.constitution = 13
        self.intelligence = 12
        self.wisdom = 8
        self.charisma = 10

player = Player()

print(player.__dict__)
player_dict = player.__dict__

# Define list of attributes you are allowed to change
attributes = ["strength", "dexterity", "constitution", "intelligence", "wisdom", "charisma"]
player_dict_subset = {k: v for k, v in player_dict.items() if k in attributes}

# Find the minimum attribute name
min_attribute = min(player_dict_subset, key=player_dict_subset.get)
print("Minimum attribute:", min_attribute)

# Add one to min attribute
player_dict[min_attribute] += 1
print(player.__dict__)

# Choose random attribute name
random_attribute = random.choice(list(player_dict_subset.keys()))
print("Random attribute:", random_attribute)
player_dict[random_attribute] += 1

print(player.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'strength': 15, 'dexterity': 14, 'constitution': 13, 'intelligence': 12, 'wisdom': 8, 'charisma': 10}
Minimum attribute: wisdom
{'strength': 15, 'dexterity': 14, 'constitution': 13, 'intelligence': 12, 'wisdom': 9, 'charisma': 10}
Random attribute: charisma
{'strength': 15, 'dexterity': 14, 'constitution': 13, 'intelligence': 12, 'wisdom': 9, 'charisma': 11}
```

Note: Editing player_dict_subset will not change the object's attributes because it was made from a dict comprehension. You need to edit player.__dict__ or player_dict instead.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I do have a problem, though..The class has many, many attributes besides the 6 that I need. How can I specify just those 6?

Comment: You can define a list of allowed attributes to change. I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Amazing. Not only does it work perfectly, it affords me the opportunity to pore over this code, combine it with your explanation and what I have already learned. Another powerful tool in my toolbox! Thank you so very much!  def increase_lowest_ability(self):
        # this code I was unable to come up with on my own. thanks to Angus Nicolson from Stack Overflow!

Comment: While the answer is surely correct, it could be better to group those 6 attributes in a single dictionary, such as `self.skills = {'strength':15, 'dexterity':14, ...}`, and perform all the operations described above on that dictionary instead of `__dict__`

Comment: Yep, if you don't mind changing the structure of your class then @gimix's is a cleaner option